# How to get page URL by title in wordpress? (get_page_by_title() function has been deprecated scince 6.2.0)

Tags: php, wordpress

I use

```
get_page_by_title()
```

sometimes in my code, for example

```
get_page_by_title($article['title'], OBJECT, 'post');
```

but now documentation says [i cant use it anymore](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_by_title/). It was pretty convenient for the purpose of testing some features where I can't use ids because of creating content on different databeses for testing purposes.
Is there any way except using `WP_Query` class because its look like a pain to use it just for getting link by the title of the post

I am looking for something like

```
get_url_by_title('title', 'post')
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: The deprecation notice on that page already told you - _"Use WP_Query instead."_

Comment: Or https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/377508

Comment: @CBroe Yeah I get you, I was asking "Is there any way except using WP_Query class because it's look like a pain". It feels like a downgrade. Now I have to use array of arguments, query the object, look through the object etc. `get_page_by_title()` was convenient. Now it's not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned @CBroe in comments, the best substitution for deprecated `get_page_by_title()` is `get_posts()` [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/). Ok, I know that documentation says: "Use WP_Query instead.", but it looks like pain.

So back to solution.
To get a **single** page or post by title, use

```
$array_of_objects = get_posts([
    'title' => 'Post or page title',
    'post_type' => 'any',
]);
$id = $array_of_objects[0];//Be sure you have an array with single post or page 
$id = $id->ID;
$link = get_permalink($id);
```

There are some moments. `'post_type' => 'any'` works better than particular post type. Do not forget that `get_posts()` returns an array of objects, so you need to refer to an array and then to object.

But if you need to get a link for a single category, you can use

```
$id = get_cat_ID($title);
$link = get_category_link($id);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I do it with WP_Query

```
function new_get_page_by_title( $page_title, $output = OBJECT, $post_type = 'page' ) {
    $args  = array(
        'title'                  => $page_title,
        'post_type'              => $post_type,
        'post_status'            => get_post_stati(),
        'posts_per_page'         => 1,
        'update_post_term_cache' => false,
        'update_post_meta_cache' => false,
        'no_found_rows'          => true,
        'orderby'                => 'post_date ID',
        'order'                  => 'ASC',
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    $pages = $query->posts;

    if ( empty( $pages ) ) {
        return null;
    }

    return get_post( $pages[0], $output );
}
```

Comment: That's fine, the question was to avoid WP_Query)) But I appreciate your effort. Thank you for your solution!

Answer (score 3):

Well, since the reason to deprecate this function is stupid [corporate non-sense ala Automattic https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/57041 ]

You can just un-deprecate it! Use this function instead:

```
function getPageByTitle( $page_title, $output = OBJECT, $post_type = 'page' ){

    global $wpdb;

    if ( is_array( $post_type ) ) {
        $post_type           = esc_sql( $post_type );
        $post_type_in_string = "'" . implode( "','", $post_type ) . "'";
        $sql                 = $wpdb->prepare(
            "
            SELECT ID
            FROM $wpdb->posts
            WHERE post_title = %s
            AND post_type IN ($post_type_in_string)
        ",
            $page_title
        );
    } else {
        $sql = $wpdb->prepare(
            "
            SELECT ID
            FROM $wpdb->posts
            WHERE post_title = %s
            AND post_type = %s
        ",
            $page_title,
            $post_type
        );
    }

    $page = $wpdb->get_var( $sql );

    if ( $page ) {
        return get_post( $page, $output );
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this. Not perfect obviously, but it works for me.

```
function my_get_page_by_title( $title, $type = 'page', $output = OBJECT ) {

    $pages = get_posts( [
        'title'     => $title,
        'post_type' => $type,
    ] );

    return ! empty( $pages[0] ) ? get_post( $pages[0]->ID, $output ) : null;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
get_permalink( get_page_by_title('Monthly Events');
```

For more detail please visit the [reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/).

Comment: The whole question is because `get_page_by_title()` is not working anymore since WordPress update 6.2.0 ))

Comment: get_page_by_title is deprecated since wordpress version 6.2.0. It would be better to use either WP_Query or get_permalink() based on page ID to fetch URL.